# Scala with Android

Tags: android, scala

I'm trying to use scala with android , my application is just contain a button as it clicked it opened a link in browser I have followed this [link](https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-button-example/) the change only is that I converted the java code to scala ?

`res.layout.main.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button - Go to mkyong.com" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`MyAndroidAppActivity.scala` :

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.view.View
import android.view.View.OnClickListener

class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {
  var button: Button = null

  override def onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle): Unit = {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.main)
    addListenerOnButton()
  }

  def addListenerOnButton(): Unit = {
    button = findViewById(R.id.button1).asInstanceOf[Button]
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      override def onClick(arg0: View): Unit = {
        val browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.mkyong.com"))
        startActivity(browserIntent)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

I got this error  :

```
Error:(16, 20) not found: value R
    setContentView(R.layout.main) 
Error:(21, 27) not found: value R
    button = findViewById(R.id.button1).asInstanceOf[Button]
```

any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear how you build your Android application. Probably with Gradle. Is Gradle build aware of Scala?

Try one of libraries to work with Scala in Android

https://scala-android.org/
https://github.com/scala-android/sbt-android
https://gitter.im/scala-android/sbt-android

https://github.com/pocorall/scaloid
http://blog.scaloid.org/

https://github.com/47deg/macroid
http://47deg.github.io/macroid/

Comment: I used sbt as build tool